# Deal with this keyword inside a react native class function

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to make double click work for react native button. But code did not work for me.

```
  _handleImagePress(e) {
    const time = new Date().getTime();
    const delta = time - this.lastPress;

    const DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY = 300;
    if (delta < DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY) {
      alert('success') //alert 1
    }
    this.lastPress = time;
    alert(this.lastPress) //alert 2
  };
```

the alert 2 is showing undefined. The this.lastPress works in node

Answer (score 0):

you may use the ["setTime0ut"](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers) function

```
_handleImagePress(e) {
    this.setState({pressed:true});
    alert('success'); //alert 1
    this.setTimeout(()=> {this.setState({pressed:false};},3000);
};
```

Comment: this.lastPress don't have any value set even though `this.lastPress = time;` code executed early

Comment: I edited my code. you can set the timeout value (3000), this is your lastPress time. If this.state.pressed  != false is till TRUE, you can do other options. Here, this.state.pressed = 'first', this.state.pressed = 'done', this.state.pressed= 'ready' etc... you can set the Text type.